# postgres : Password login error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have installed postgreSQL and I have made a password for Postgres 'admin'. I can log in with the postgres and password as long as its in the local host, as soon as I change the host form localhost to an IP it doesn't accept the password, we have another user that I can use but since its not a superuser I cant modify or make procedures is pgAdmin.

So the question is: Can I somehow reset the password for the postgres, I have tried to modify pg_hpa.config

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                trust
```

but that did me no good, so any suggestions of how to reset, or add a password (I also tried this on: `ALTER USER postgres VALID UNTIL 'infinity';`) or change is would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error message when trying to connect non-locally?

Comment: It said that the password was incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have this problem resolved, I couldn't get in there because I only had the local password but fortunately our database manager got the postgres password for the IP that we use. Sorry to have taken up your time guys and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
[Postgres password](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/006201c74b23$17cce130$9b0014ac@wbaus090)

or this:
[Stackoverflow Postgres Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644/postgres-password-authentication-fails)

Comment: Well I might have done something wrong, anyway it still asks the password from me, and I couldnt see the other tips because they were confidential

Comment: Here's a final link which might help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36137/postgresql-user-can-not-connect-to-server-after-changing-password