# Password authentication failing for Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm creating a Rails app and using a Postgresql database with it. I've created a few tables and a user, `core`, which is the owner of each of the tables.

```
postgres=# create user core with password 'n7zD5FG5';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create database core_apps_prod with owner core;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# create database core_apps_dev with owner core;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# create database core_apps_test with owner core;
CREATE DATABASE
```

And my `database.yml` file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: core_apps_dev
  username: core
  password: n7zD5FG5
  host: localhost
```

However, when I run `rake db:migrate`, I get the error

```
rake aborted!
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "core"
```

I also cannot connect to `psql` manually: `psql -U core -W -d core_apps_dev` - I get the same error.

How can I allow `core` to connect to Postgresql on `localhost`?

The output of `SELECT * FROM pg_roles where rolname='core';` is:

```
 rolname | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcatupdate | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolconfig |  oid  
---------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------
 core    | f        | t          | f             | f           | f            | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               |           | 16392
```

Comment: Add `-h localhost` to psql to connect to localhost, otherwise it's using Unix domain sockets which have different authentication rules. Also by using `-W` you won't know whether the server requires a password or not, which adds to the confusion when troubleshooting password problems. Just omit `-W`

Comment: I tried that, by running the command `psql -h localhost -U core -d core_apps_dev` and entering the password, but it still says `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "core"`. I made doubly sure that the password is correct by running `ALTER USER core PASSWORD 'n7zD5FG5';` but it still failed.

Comment: What you did works for me. At this point I'd suspect a few possibilities: 1. having created the account on a different PG instance. 2. [pgadmin bug on valuntil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644), although you never mentioned pgadmin. 3. Weirdness in pg_hba.conf. 4. weirdness in postgresql.conf on auth options. To clear out a bit, I'd set the auth method to `trust` in pg_hba.conf on the relevant line, reload PG and retry. It should connect without asking for a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an issue with the port. The Postgresql Activerecord adapter [defaults to port `5432`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html), while the port in my configuration was port `5433`. My `database.yml` now looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: core_apps_dev
  username: core
  password: n7zD5FG5
  host: localhost
  port: 5433
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add privileges to the role when you create it. To allow logging in and using `rake db:create` use the following:

```
create role core with login createdb password 'n7zD5FG5';
```

To fix your problem, try altering the role to allow login:

```
alter role core with login;
```

And if that doesn't work, see if making the login valid forever works:

```
alter role core valid until 'infinity';
```

More about roles: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createrole.html

Edit:

I also had to do this when I installed postgres:

```
$ psql postgres -c 'CREATE EXTENSION "adminpack";'
```

Comment: I believe that `core` has login privilege. I ran `SELECT * FROM pg_roles;` and `core` has the role `rolcanlogin`.

Comment: yeah just read `create user` implies the login role. see if the password is valid, and if that's not it, not sure what is

Answer (score -1):

The newly created user probably is lacking database privileges. There are many different privileges you can give to a user.

Assuming that you have admin account access to psql, go into psql and run

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE core_apps_dev to core;`

Comment: It doesn't have all privileges to the database when it's the owner?

Comment: Yes, you will give admin privileges this way. [More on database privileges for postgresql...](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html)

Comment: So, if I create the database with owner `core`, it should have all privileges on the database?

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try

```
alter role core with password "n7zD5FG5";
```