# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-9.1, psycopg2

getting this error message in ubuntu. in pg_hba.conf file, I tried using 'ident','peer','trust','md5' in different times.but no go. please help.

Comment: Same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644/postgres-password-authentication-fails)

Comment: Did you do any searching / research first? Show your config files. Explain what you tried. Show the commands and errors.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

in your pg_hba.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32         trust
```

if it does not work then try with

```
host    all         all         your_ip/32         trust
```

then restart your data base
it will work fine

Comment: You, sir, are a saint. Thanks

Comment: For quick reference, on Ubuntu the command to restart database is `sudo service postgresql restart`.

Answer (score 2):

If the username and password are correct then `md5` is the correct value. Make sure you restart the database process or at least have it reload the configuration after modifying `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: muchas gracias @fog. restarting postgresql server resolved my issue.

Comment: how to you restart the database process? ```pg_ctl restart``` isn't working for me

Answer (score 1):

It might be came from malicious traffic, check if the logs repeated almost each seconds like below

```
2019-04-17 16:10:39.228 UTC [32] FATAL:  
        password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2019-04-17 16:10:39.228 UTC [32] DETAIL:  
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
2019-04-17 16:10:41.916 UTC [33] FATAL:  
        password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2019-04-17 16:10:41.916 UTC [33] DETAIL:  
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
...
...
```

Lets verify TCP Traffic on port 5432 using [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/) command

```
$ sudo tcpdump port 5432 and '(tcp-syn|tcp-ack)!=0'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:19:26.472838 IP XX-XXX-XXX-XXX-static.xxx.xxxxxx.net.39903 > xxx.xxx.xxx: Flags [S], seq 1779566115, win 29200, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 451453976 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:19:26.473135 IP xxx.xxx.xxx > XX-XXX-XXX-XXX-static.xxx.xxxxxx.net.39903: Flags [S.], seq 4028889669, ack 1779566116, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2412144 ecr 451453976,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:19:26.525816 IP XX-XXX-XXX-XXX-static.xxx.xxxxxx.net.39903 > xxx.xxx.xxx: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 451453989 ecr 2412144], length 0
16:19:26.525875 IP xxx.xxx.xxx > XX-XXX-XXX-XXX-static.xxx.xxxxxx.net: Flags [P.], seq 1:42, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 451453989 ecr 2412144], length 41
...
...
```

If this is the case then set [firewall rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) and necessary securities to combat bots or unwanted traffics.

Comment: After looking at a bunch of forums this is the first one to tell me these logs are coming from malicious traffic. Thank you sir. I'll be implementing [iptables](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables) for anyone interested in firewall tools

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I've created my user with an expiration date of yesterday.
It also gave me the password error.
I've opened pgadmin3 and in the users list at the bottom I've changed the expiration date of the problematic user.