# pgAdmin III can connect to Heroku Postgresql. PDO can't connect to same database. Why?

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, pdo, pgadmin

i'm new here and I apologize if I'm doing something wrong for post my question.

My question is quite simple:
From my machine I can connect pgAdmin III to a remote postgreSql (provide by Heroku). I can read/write my database without problems.

Unfortunately, **from the same machine**, I can't connect a PHP page using PDO extension (it  work perfectly). The error it give to me is:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x", user "username", database "myDatabase", SSL off

I should edit "pg_hba.conf" for resolve, but unfortunately I can't edit it on Heroku (or maybe I don't know how to do).

I don't understand why pgAdmin III can connect but my PHP page can't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! First of all, please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Next, you want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You will get your ans in the following ans
I think your `user` have no entry `in pg_hba.conf` file and your `pgAdmin III` and `PHP` users are different
[check the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137726/fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres/21184006#21184006)

Comment: My error was I forgot "sslmode=require" in my connection string. Now error is "sslmode value 'require' invalid when SSL support is not compiled in".
OpenSSl is installed. 

What is wrong?

Comment: @ElMander Your comment is not clearly understood by me. will you give some more details.