# Getting error:Peer authentication failed while connecting octave to psql database

Tags: octave, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to connect to a psql database from octave but getting a peer authentication failed error.

error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user

error: PQ connection attempt failed

Comment: Which package are you using? octave-forge database? http://octave.sourceforge.net/database/index.html please also mention Octaves version

Answer (score 0):

check your pg_hba.conf file I think in that file there is no entry of your current user.

or see the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137726/fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres/21184006#21184006)