# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, postgresql-9.3

Recently, I have installed PostgreSQL 9.3 on my windows 7 64 bit PC but today I have formatted my PC. Now again I tried to install PostgreSQL 9.3 but after installation when I tried to connect it throws error See below screenshot :-

[image]

My pg_hba.conf is shown below :

[image]

I have also saw [Postgres password authentication fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644/postgres-password-authentication-fails) but nothing helps.

I am new to PostgreSQL,please help me on this.

Comment: You're using the wrong password. If you've lost/forgotten your password, you can change `pg_hba.conf` to use `trust` for long eough to reset it - see "reset postgres password".

Comment: @CraigRinger I have used the password which I have put during installation. Should I change method = Trust on pg_hba.conf ?

Comment: @CraigRinger I have change that to trust and restart but still it is asking for password and when I put the password it shows "role rakesh does not exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution hope this will help to other users if they are facing the same problem :-

I have to edit `pg_hba.conf` file which is located in "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data". In that file I have to make method md5 to trust as @Craig Ringer said. So the line will look like `host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 trust`.

Then to restart the PostgreSQL on windows - Go to `start > run > services.msc` then restart the service.

Then open pg Admin create new server enter all the required details and save it. That's it !!