# Error Connecting to the Server

Tags: windows, postgresql

I got the following error in my windows PC when I tried to connect server in postgreSQL

```
An error has occured:
Error connecting to the server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: I guess you have the wrong password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should check if the username is correct.

Comment: Please use the comments to ask questions.

Comment: I wanted to but my reputation is too low it said

Comment: This is why: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment . The following link explains how you can earn reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: I understand the reason. Just telling you why I used answer instead of comment. Anyway - suggestion to check username seems valid to me.

Comment: I agree that it is a valid question to ask given the details available. If you edit your question to be in the form of an answer / solution I'll remove the downvote. :)

Comment: Ok. Now it's more of a suggestion :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63012/discussion-between-bartosz-janik-and-vegard).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the proper settings in pg_hba.conf?

See https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postgresql.html how to do it.

Comment: simply check your username and password...or go for the settings

Comment: Why are you posting a link to an Ubuntu configuration when the question is about **Windows**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644/postgres-password-authentication-fails

you can check over here brother..