# Setting password for PostgreSQL user doesn't work

Tags: postgresql

I'm stuck.

**The task:** I need to have a certain Postgres user to own certain database with predefined password. Basically, I just don't want to maintain separate development settings for Django project apart from those present in our project's repo.

**Prerequisites:** PostgreSQL 9.1 on Ubuntu, database 'project' which has the owner 'project'. The 'project' user is seems to be also superuser, and should have the password 'project'. Of course there are fake names, just because of NDA. *Note:* I'm able to log in as 'postgres' user, that's how I use the database right now.

**The problem:** I tried a set of ways, mostly obvious which can be found here on Stackoverflow or in Google, to set a password to this user, but still having 'password authentication failed' message (see below).

*What I've tried:*

- setting up password via PgAdmin
- setting up password through `ALTER ROLE project WITH PASSWORD 'project'`
- changing settings in `pg_hba.conf`, tried `local all project peer`, `local all project md5`

Maybe I'm missing something straightforward, please let me know.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here is a screenshot for this user from login roles pane -
[image: Login roles pane]

Comment: Could you post the info from pgAdmin SQL pane, from Login roles > project (you can change confidential data of course).

Comment: Did you reset postgres after tweaking those configuration files? Otherwise the password change won't have effect. sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @brunch875: changing `pg_hba.conf` doesn't require a restart, just a reload of the config ( `pg_ctl ... reload`)

Comment: Django app is running on the same server as the database?

Comment: Posted a screenshot from Login roles pane. Yes, I always do `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart` after any settings change. Error message is `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "project"`. Yes, Django app is running on the same server, it's all on my notebook.

Comment: "*password authentication failed*"  means you supplied the wrong password when connecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that part at the bottom of your screenshot:

> .. VALID UNTIL '1970-01-01 00:00:00:

or the "Account Expires" field above

That expiration date is wrong and explains why this account can't login.

Presumably you've been bitten by the pgAdmin bug mentioned here:

[Postgres password authentication fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644/postgres-password-authentication-fails)

TL;DR solution: `ALTER USER username VALID UNTIL 'infinity';`

(and of course update pgAdmin).

Answer (score 0):

Is the LOGIN attribute set in your role? CREATE ROLE does not set this attribute by default. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/role-attributes.html

Comment: Seems it's set, see attached screenshot.