# Unable to log in to postgres on windows after fresh installation - "psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres""

Tags: postgresql, psql

EDIT: WINDOWS: Yes Windows. Do not redirect me to answers that specify sudo-ing because, hey, I can't sudo on Windows.

I have just done a fresh install of postgres 11 on *Windows* and I am getting

```
C:\Users\J\Documents\Development>psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file "C:\Users\J\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf"
```

Note that I do not get an opportunity to enter a password - i.e. I do NOT get a password prompt.  There is a password in the pgpass.conf file.  I am running the cmd.exe box as Administrator.

There is a link to psql in the folder created at installation but that is no good either. It identically does not ask for a password.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1471571/62576 and several others.

Comment: You will see Ken White that all of those others (at least, all of the ones that I saw) reference non-Windows installations.  Any answer that contains instructions to sudo is not applicable here.  Hence, my italicization of Windows.

Comment: Ok. Try these instead (all for Windows): https://stackoverflow.com/q/31028623/62576, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47311101/62576, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7086654/62576.. As I said, **and several others**. Searching this site found those within 2 minutes of reading your comment. Add `[windows]` before the error message when searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password file [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html).

To get a password prompt, locate the file in `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` and delete it.

It was probably created automatically by pgAdmin.

If there is an entry in the password file that matches your login, you won't be prompted, and the password is taken from the file. If you delete the file, you will be prompted for a password (if `pg_hba.conf` is configured accordingly).

Comment: but there is not such folder "postgresql" in appdata

Comment: @Kloody Why, then create it.

Comment: what is the point of creating single file.

Comment: Anyway, I found the file already in progfiles directory and fixed the issue in a more inhumane way. have a nice day.