# sails-postgresql error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js

I'm building a Sails.js app, and I set up the sails-postgresql adapter with all of my connection info and it worked fine the first time I lifted the app and created all of my tables.

Now I get this error:

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
at Connection.parseE (/root/royaltyPayer/vigilant-disco/royaltyPayer/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:540:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/root/royaltyPayer/vigilant-disco/royaltyPayer/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:367:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/royaltyPayer/vigilant-disco/royaltyPayer/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:535:20)
```

I have already tried all of the answers posted to this question: [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)

I have made sure that my linux password and database password for user postgres are the same.

Here is the relevant line from /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

Here is my code in config/connections.js:

```
module.exports.connections = {
PostgresqlServer: {
  adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'postgres',
  password: '12345',
  port:'5433',
  database: 'myDB'
}
```

Here is my code in config/models.js

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'PostgresqlServer',
  migrate: 'safe'
}
```

I am using: 
Sails version 0.11.0,
Postgres version 9.4,
Node version 6.0.0

My permissions on the database in psql:

```
                                      List of databases
 Name      |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |     Access privileges
---------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------
 myDB | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres              +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Comment: Check if it's the same issue as [Postgres password authentication fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644)

Comment: Note that `host: 'localhost'` does not correspond to `local` connection type in pg_hba.conf, it corresponds to `host` connection type with `localhost` as the address. It's not the reason of your error, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @DanielVérité but it is not the same issue. This user was not created using pgadmin.
I did try altering the validity to infinity as suggested, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Another possibility is that you set the password in a different instance than the one the program tries to connect to. That might be a long shot, but you're using 5433 as the port. Generally when doing that, it's because there is another instance running on the default port (5432).

Comment: I'm not sure why it's running on port 5433 (and only that port), but it is.

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN