# "ATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres

Tags: postgresql

I install postgres12 with pgadmin 4 on windows with Wsl.

But when i want to launch my script or do something, i got this error :
ATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres

I see some forum about it, and I try some solution before ask but not work

Forum that I see and try solution :

-[Postgres password authentication fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644/postgres-password-authentication-fails?rq=1)

-https://qastack.fr/programming/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres

I change too, the file pg_hba.conf and i put all the line in md5

I got the file log here :

[File Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO1fT.png)

Maybe someone have another solution for me please?

Thanx all :)

Ps: sorry for my english

Comment: The message returned to the unauthenticated (and so presumably hostile) client is intentionally vague.  Look in the server log file for the full error message.

Comment: I put the file log in edit message :)

Comment: The bit of log file looks garbled up, but it looks like "postgres" doesn't have a password assigned to it, and it also looks like other attempts are to log in as a username which starts with "postgres" but then ends with some control characters (or maybe a newline and linefeed characters?)

Comment: The log are the same for all attempt connection (the same message just with different time(hour) of connection, here it's the log of my last try)
I put a password to the postgres user when i create Database, and i try to rename it after but all same..

Thanx for your answer =)